# C/C++: `const` position in function's argument list

Tags: c++, constants

```
void func1 (const int *);
void func2 (int const *);
void func3 (int * const);
```

Which two signatures are equivalent? If none of them are, can you please explain the subtle differences?

Comment: 1 and 2 are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the other question! It offers an great way to remember how they work, "Read it backwards."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two are equivalent (the int is const), in the third it's the pointer that's const (i.e. the parameter itself).